# Maven: Using different plugin configurations on e.g. deploy

Tags: maven, maven-3

For an android maven project (consisting out of a parent project that consists out of the main apk project and a test project), I would like to be able to use different plugin configurations for building the whole project.

I know that I can do this with profiles, but are there any other options?

The thing I would like to achieve is to execute a deploy with "mvn deploy" and to use a different plugin configuration, that should only be used if a deploy (or release) is taking place.

A concrete example would be to increase the android version code only if a deploy takes place. Binding the increase of the version code directly to the deploy phase does not work as the increased version code is needed before the process-resources phase to work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid maven profiles are your only option.

You could add an enforcer check on `deploy` phase to fail the build if a profile is not active:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
  <executions>
     <execution>
       <phase>deploy</phase> <!-- enfoce rules on `mvn deploy` -->
       <goals>
         <goal>enforce</goal>
       </goals>
     </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
     <rules>
       <requireActiveProfile>
         <profiles>prod</profiles> <!-- require `-Pprod` -->
       </requireActiveProfile>
     </rules>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```